# Pass closure to FunctionType in function

Tags: python, testing, closures

I have a code like this:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def outer_method(self):
        def inner_method():
            return self.a +1
        return inner_method()
```

I want to write a test for `inner_method`. For that, I am using a code like this:

```
def find_nested_func(parent, child_name):
    """ 
       Return the function named <child_name> that is defined inside
        a <parent> function
        Returns None if nonexistent
    """
    consts = parent.__code__.co_consts
    item = list(filter(lambda x:isinstance(x, CodeType) and x.co_name==child_name, consts ))[0]
    return FunctionType(item, globals())
```

Calling it with `find_nested_func(A().outer_method, 'inner_method')` but it fails when calling to 'FunctionType' because the function cannot be created since 'self.a' stops existing in the moment the function stops being an inner function. I know the construction FunctionType can recive as an argument a closure that could fix this problem , but I don't know how to use it. How can I pass it?

The error it gives is the next one:

```
    return FunctionType(item, globals())
TypeError: arg 5 (closure) must be tuple
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to test `inner_method`? In most cases, you should only test parts of your public API. `outer_method` is part of `A`'s public API, so test just that. `inner_method` is an implementation detail that can change: what if you decide to rename it? what if you refactor it slightly without modifying the externally visible behavior of `outer_method`? Users of the class `A` have no (easy) way of calling `inner_method`. Unit tests are usually only meant to test things that users of your class can call (I'm assuming these are for unit tests, because integration tests this granular would be strange--and the same principle would still mostly hold).

Practically, you'll have a problem extracting functions defined within another function's scope, for several reasons include variable capture. You have no way of knowing if `inner_method` only captures `self` or if `outer_method` performs some logic and computes some variables that `inner_method` uses. For example:

```
class A:
    def outer_method():
        b = 1

        def inner_method():
            return self.a + b

        return inner_method()
```

Additionally, you could have control statements around the function definition, so there is no way to decide which definition is used without running `outer_method`. For example:

```
import random

class A:
    def outer_method():
        if random.random() < 0.5:
            def inner_method():
                return self.a + 1
        else:
            def inner_method():
                return self.a + 2

        return inner_method()
```

You can't extract `inner_method` here because there are two of them and you don't know which is actually used until you run `outer_method`.

So, just don't test `inner_method`.

If `inner_method` is truly complex enough that you want to test it in isolation (and if you do so, principled testing says you should mock out its uses, eg. its use in `outer_method`), then just make it a "private-ish" method on `A`:

```
class A:
    def _inner_method(self):
        return self.a + 1
    def outer_method(self):
        return self._inner_method()
```

Principled testing says you really shouldn't be testing underscore methods, but sometimes necessity requires it. Doing this things way allows you test `_inner_method` just as you would any other method. Then, when testing `outer_method`, you could mock it out by doing `a._inner_method = Mock()` (where `a` is the `A` object under test).

Also, use `class A`. The parens are unnecessary unless you have parent classes.

Comment: I undestand your point. I want to do the test for the inner function because the operations it does are quite complex, so it would be nice to be able to easily detect if the error is happening in the inner or the outer function. And it must be an inner and not private because it would give problems when doing some operations due to certain libraries it is using.

Comment: For cases like that, I'd recommend the last approach at the end of my answer. As I explained above, extracting the inner method at runtime will be tricky if not impossible in some cases.

Comment: I cannot do something like:

    def _inner_method(self):
            return self.a + 1

Because the method cannot receibe any argument (neither self)  because it will be passed to a library that is not prepared to use methods that recive arguments.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, but `self` isn't a passed argument. It's implicit. When you do `A()._inner_method()` you don't have to pass the `self`. If you wanted to pass `_inner_method` to someone you can just do `foo = A()._inner_method`. `foo` is bound to `self`, so a user of this could just do `foo()`. Also how is the library that's using `inner_method` getting at it in the first place if it is an inner method? As I described above, that's tricky to begin with. Finally, if `inner_method` is used by a library, then make it a public method (remove the leading `_`) and test it separately.